# What is the correct way of inserting \u using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm trying to find a string that contains `\u` and adding something to it.

For example,

```
$ echo \user | sed 's/\us/\\usX/' -
```

correctly produces

```
\usXer
```

However, if I have the contents in a file and input it to the following code

```
$ sed -i 's/\us/\\usX/' test
```

I get

```
\\usXer
```

Then, one might think that the problem is the escaped backslash, and it is not needed. But if one removes it, that only triggers the `\u` (uppercase) substitution of the `s` command of `sed`.

Thus, what is the correct way of inserting a `\u` sequence using `sed`?

Comment: I advise you to (1) use quotes more often, and (2) decompose commands if you aren’t 110% sure what the components are doing.  Your first example is getting the “right” result for the wrong reason.  `echo \user` writes `user` to the standard output (which you would know if you had tried it by itself).  To write `\user`, use `echo \\user`, `echo "\user"`, or `echo '\user'`.  And then `sed 's/\us/\\usX/'` changes `us` to `\usX` (which you would know if you had tried `echo bus | sed 's/\us/\\usX/'`), i.e., the `sed` command is *inserting* the ``\`` that you thought was in your input.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And, when you actually put `\user` into a file (presumably with a text editor), you end up getting `\\usXer` because the `sed` command is ignoring the ``\`` and the `er` that are already in the file, and replacing `us` with `\usX`.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Also, (3), `sed`, like very many \*nix programs, reads from the standard input if given no filename arguments, so you don’t need to say `sed (command) -`; it’s good enough to say `sed (command)`.  (You would need to use **`-`** in contexts like `command_that_generates_data2 | sed (command) file1 - file3`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `sed 's/\us/…/'` doesn't search for `\us`;
it searches for `us`. 
To search for `\us`, you need to use `sed 's/\\us/…/'`.

If you're searching for a string with special characters in it,
and then *adding* something to it,
a useful technique is to use the `&` character
to refer to the string that you searched for.  So, for example,

```
$ sed -i 's/\\us/&X/' test
```

In general, `&` (sometimes called the "Find What") represents that portion of the pattern space that matched your search string. 
This is more useful when the search string is a non-simple regular expression; e.g.,

```
$ echo You say goodbye and I say hello. | sed 's/[gh][a-z]*[eo]/"&"/g'
You say "goodbye" and I say "hello".
```

Just as `'s/\\usmthing/…/'` is the way to search for `\usmthing`,
you need to use `'s/…/\\usmthing/'` to insert `\usmthing`.
For example,

```
$ echo Boo | sed 's/oo/\ulish/'
BLish                  ← Note that \ul was interpreted to mean "put ‘l’ into upper case".

$ echo Boo | sed 's/oo/\\ulish/'
B\ulish
```

Comment: That does the trick because I don't insert the `\u`. But, what if I wanted to insert it by hand?

Comment: Then this should do:


    sed -i 's/\\us/\\usX' test

Comment: You should leave both answers in your post, mostly because the bit about `&` is a good answer to the question, but also because you still have the introductory paragraph that says, "How about using & as in ...".